# portaudio: how to play a new audio after another that just finished

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

I am trying to play a new audio after another one.
The situation is like this:

I play one sinusoidal wave and wait until it stop - until callback returns PaComplete. After that, I wait for a rand time and then play a new wave - that is a pseudocode from the tutorials:

```
    err = Pa_OpenDefaultStream( &stream,
               0, /* no input channels */
               2, /* stereo output */
               paFloat32, /* 32 bit floating point output */
               SAMPLE_RATE,
               256, /* frames per buffer */
               patestCallback,
               &data );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    while( Pa_Active() );

    err = Pa_StopStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;
    err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    err = Pa_OpenDefaultStream( &stream,
               0, /* no input channels */
               2, /* stereo output */
               paFloat32, /* 32 bit floating point output */
               SAMPLE_RATE,
               256, /* frames per buffer */
               patestCallback,
               &data );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    while( Pa_Active() );

    err = Pa_StopStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;
    err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;
```

As you can see, I just replicated the code, however when I try to play, no sound is generated for the second wave, and, if I call Pa_getErrorText, it always says 'Success'.
Can anyone help me with this.

PS. that is the sawtooth tutorial with replicated code. The wave I am use is differente however.